# I am working on BIRT reporting

Tags: birt

Is that possible to get multiple parameter values based on another parameter value. For example if I select facility id ,then it should populate below region and FQA parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use cascading parameters. Check out this URL to see if it is close to what you are aiming for... https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/503715/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `cascading parameter group`. [Here is an example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhFFwRwx11Q) on how to use it.